# How to Make a menu with product category Dynamically in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook, hook-woocommerce

I have a question, can I make menu with product category with one click or Dynamically in WordPress
I have many category And Very Time consuming to make this
I found a plugin for this :

> https://awesometogi.com/dynamic-menu-product-categories/

but I don't know  work this

Answer (score 11):

You can do that with a bit of code by forcing WooCommerce categories to be added to a specific menu ID.

Add this to your theme's functions.php file:

```
function _custom_nav_menu_item( $title, $url, $order, $parent = 0 ){
  $item = new stdClass();
  $item->ID = 1000000 + $order + $parent;
  $item->db_id = $item->ID;
  $item->title = $title;
  $item->url = $url;
  $item->menu_order = $order;
  $item->menu_item_parent = $parent;
  $item->type = '';
  $item->object = '';
  $item->object_id = '';
  $item->classes = array();
  $item->target = '';
  $item->attr_title = '';
  $item->description = '';
  $item->xfn = '';
  $item->status = '';
  return $item;
}
add_filter("wp_get_nav_menu_items", function ($items, $menu, $args) {
    if( $menu->term_id != 24 ) return $items; // Where 24 is Menu ID, so the code won't affect other menus.

    // don't add child categories in administration of menus
    if (is_admin()) {
        return $items;
    }
    $ctr = ($items[sizeof($items)-1]->ID)+1;
    foreach ($items as $index => $i)
    {
        if ("product_cat" !== $i->object) {
            continue;
        }
        $menu_parent = $i->ID;
        $terms = get_terms( array('taxonomy' => 'product_cat', 'parent'  => $i->object_id ) );
        foreach ($terms as $term) {
            $new_item = _custom_nav_menu_item( $term->name, get_term_link($term), $ctr, $menu_parent );
            $items[] = $new_item;
            $new_id = $new_item->ID;
            $ctr++;
            $terms_child = get_terms( array('taxonomy' => 'product_cat', 'parent'  => $term->term_id ) );
            if(!empty($terms_child))
            {
                foreach ($terms_child as $term_child)
                {
                    $new_child = _custom_nav_menu_item( $term_child->name, get_term_link($term_child), $ctr, $new_id );
                    $items[] = $new_child;
                    $ctr++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $items;
}, 10, 3);
```

In the above code notice the `$menu->term_id != 24` part. Then change the value of `24` with your menu ID.

The code above will also exclude empty product categories.

There is also a plugin which can do the same and not just product categories: https://wordpress.org/plugins/jc-submenu/

Comment: code does not work my menu id is "wp-admin/nav-menus.php?menu=386"

Comment: Therefore instead of `24` in that code you would only add `386`. If that doesn't work I am not sure how to troubleshoot it. Try to see if there are any errors. Or perhaps that plugin may help.

Comment: @MistaPrime your reply was a HUGE help towards solving the same problem I had. The only thing that you didn't mention was that we had to manually add the initial (top-level) product categories, and then your script kicks in to populate them with their subcategories. What I'm investigating right now, is a way to 1. make it completely dynamic - in a way that it will create even the initial / top-level categories, and 2. make it identify the current page, so that it will add the correct formatting class to the top-level category when in a subcategory underneath it (if you get what I mean)...

Comment: @FayeD. were you able to make it fully dynamic?

Comment: @ptrcao do you still need help with this?

Comment: @AndrewSchultz not strictly, but for my education, I'd still be keen to see a dynamic solution.